# Laravel Eloquent instead of Query Build

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How to convert the following Laravel (v8) Query to Eloquent? That is possible?

`'house_id' => DB::table('houses') ->select('id') ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) ->orderByDesc('created_at')->value('id')`

The current query is doing the job, but I'm curious to know if the same can be done with Eloquent. In other words, there's a more elegant way to do the same?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense at all.

Thank you very much for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a [`latest()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest) function on the query builder which orders results in descending order by `created_at` date. So you could simplify your query to as follows:

```php
House::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->first()->id;
```

This might look confusing, `latest()->first()`, but `latest()` returns a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) so if you use `first()` to access the most recent record and then grab the `id` from the model.

If you find yourself using the above frequently, you could take it further and define a [`scope`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) on your `User` model.

```php
public function houses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(House::class);
}

public function scopeLatestHouse(Builder $query) {
    return $this->houses()->latest()->first();
}
```

Now all you need to do is:

```php
$latestHouse = Auth::user()->latestHouse()->id;
```

Comment: By the way, please can you refer to a good source (tutorial) where I can learn more about Eloquent (not at Laravel documentation). I will appreciate that!!

Comment: @ack2v [Laravel 8 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) is a good resource and has sections on Eloquent. [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) is a good resource in general. Not all courses are free but they are good quality and worth subscribing for when you feel it's appropriate (i.e. some of the more advanced topics).

Answer (score 0):

If your model is called **House** : `$house = House::query()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->select('id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()` or use `->first()` if you want to get only one element. Then you can call `$house->id`.

Comment: Hi Takachi, I just want to get the ID value of the house. Yes, my Model is called House.

Comment: Edited my answer. But ```select('id')``` only select the id of the house, you can also use ```->first('id')``` instead of ```->select('id)``` and ```->get()```

Comment: Like that? 

House::query()
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())
            ->select('id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->first('id')
            ->get();

In response, I want just an Integer, nothing else.

Comment: House::query()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first('id')

Comment: `DB::table('houses')
            ->select('id')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')->value('id');`

Returns 50 (for instance)

`House::query()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first('id')`

Returns the follow:

`App\Models\House {#1442 ▼
    #table: "houses"
    #guarded: []
    #fillable: array:8 [▶]
    # ...
    #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "id" => 50
  ]
`
How to grab the ID?

Comment: ```House::query()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get('id')```

Comment: It's returning a collection as follow:

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1576 ▼
  #items: array:52 [▶]
}`

The @Peppermintology answer is exactly what I need.

I appreciate your effort in trying to help me @Takachi.